# Rewriting this Line from Objective C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know this is a little trivial but for the life of me I can't seem to get this line of Objective-C Code right in Swift.

Any Ideas?

**Obj C Code:**

```
CardView *view = (CardView *)draggableView;
```

**I tried:**

```
let view : CardView = draggableView(CardView)
```

I'm probably forgetting something small.

Comment: you want `draggableView as? CardView` (if you want it to be optional) or `draggableView as! CardView` if you want it to be explicit (make sure you check type first before doing this though).

Comment: use the site https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code to convert obj-c to swift

Comment: @Mr.T I'm not sure I'd ever advise someone to just copy and paste their code to convert it into another language... OP should understand Swift before writing code in it.

Comment: I agree with you.But  sometimes, the reverse process could help too.

Comment: @originaluser2 What's the difference between coping-and-pasting code into a converter and the answers below accompanied by the word "Try -". The only difference is automation. Thank you human converters.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I think that says more about the answers below then it does about the converter...

Comment: @originaluser2 good point, everyone got what they wanted. Easy points and a one time conversion service. If only there were a tool...

Comment: Voting to close as too broad: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I see what you did there ;) At the end of the day, it's still up to the OP if he wants to just copy and paste code found on the internet or actually take the time an effort to understand a language. Only one of the paths will actually help OP in the long term though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try -

```
let view = draggableView as! CardView
```

Comment: Forced casts should be avoided, they can lead to crashes at unexpected times

Comment: Yes it depends on usage, if you are not sure then you can use ? instead of !

Answer (score 4):

```
let view = draggableView as CardView
```

See type casting https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: you can't just use a plain `as` to downcast a variable. OP needs `as?` or `as!`.

Comment: Actually you'll want to use either `as?` for a conditional cast or `as!` for a forced cast. So either of the other answers are better, because they are doing what the original Objective-C code was doing, which is a forced cast.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
let view = draggableView as! CardView
```

That should cast it to a CardView.

Comment: How different is your answer to the answer posted below ?

Comment: It isn't. We wrote them at the same time I guess. I just saw his.

Comment: @Mr.T 1) Answers don't always show in the same order so don't reference other answers by their position. 2) If the timestamp of the answers are less than 5 or 10 minutes, don't worry about seemingly duplicate answers. People take time to write their answers. Now if someone comes along an hour, a day, or a week later and posts the same answer, then speak up.

Comment: Forced casts are dangerous, they can lead to crashes when you're least expecting.